# Назви "жіночих" професій

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Чи можливо вживати слова на позначення жіночого роду, що означають певні професії (мисткиня, режисерка, економічка, драматургиня, редакторка). Чи є якась різниця між позначеннями професій жіночого роду, що звичні нам (учителька, лікарка) та даними словами?